# What does a Servlet 3.0 compatible web-app declaration in web.xml do?

Tags: java, web-applications, jetty, servlet-3.0

I am deploying a web application that is declared in web.xml and deployed as a .war file.

I am deploying on Jetty 9.1.x (but I think this question is not container specific).

My web.xml file is quite old and declares itself as a Servlet 2.4 application:

```
<web-app version="2.4" id="my_app"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
```

My configuration actually declares some Servlet 3.0 only features, like a default error page. These features do not validate according to the schema, but the features *seem* to work correctly.

Since I am using 3.0 features, I would like to change the declaration to be correct:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">
```

But I am scared to do this because I don't understand what the difference will be to Jetty.

Will changing the declaration have any effect on the runtime behavior of Jetty? Does Jetty treat a 2.4 app somehow differently than a 3.0 app?

Comment: I would think it does. For investigative purposes, add a `@WebListener` annotated class that implements `ServletContextListner` (or any other servlet listener type) to your class path with 3.0 and see if it's picked up.

Comment: My WebListener is not picked up regardless of the declaration. In all my testing, I could not find different behavior. What other feature could I test?

Comment: I think I see the problem: my app deploys gwt-servlet-2.5.1... so no matter what I do, my requests will be served through a 2.5 servlet and not a 3.0 servlet.

Comment: Yup, that's it. If you were on a Servlet 3.0 compatible container, I would think declaring a web-app version would make the container support only those features. I would try with a different container just to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to simply swap the schema declaration from **2.4** to **3.0**.

#### Scientific method

Initially I set off to prove it by doing `diff` between **2.4** and **2.5** and another one comparing **2.5** and **3.0**.

I have convinced myself that the differences between **2.4** and **2.5** are only additive and the name space have shifted from `j2ee` to `javaee`.

**However** xsd schema for **3.0** is smaller then 1/3rd of the other two versions. Not sure how to proceed in this case *(any ideas welcome!)*

You can download all schemas from here and do the comparison yourself:

- [web xml v2.4 xsd schema](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd)
- [web.xml v2.5 xsd schema](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjJzeqf7tTLAhWHbxQKHd4QDlYQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com%2Fwebfolder%2Ftechnetwork%2Fjsc%2Fxml%2Fns%2Fjavaee%2Fweb-app_2_5.xsd&usg=AFQjCNFajbQvcuQleDBoLjw6NyNEEFunWw&sig2=vGVaUswQLowtBdiLmp_f7g&cad=rja)
- [web.xml v3.0 xsd schema](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd)

#### Not so scientific method

Here are the **what's new** articles describing each new version of the standard:

- [What's new in Servlet 2.4](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073323/java-web-development/servlet-2-4--what-s-in-store.html)
- [What's new in Servlet 2.5](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071393/java-web-development/new-features-added-to-servlet-2-5.html)
- [What's new in Servlet 3.0](http://www.javabeat.net/new-features-in-servlets-3-0/)

If you read in, the changes to `web.xml` descriptor *mentioned in the articles* are minute.

What I would do is simply list all the elements in your original `web.xml` and confirm that they do exist in this document describing the [3.0 schema](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/web_xml.htm#WBAPP502).

Hope this helps!